# Mongoose Schema not converting data properly

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

So, I've a got a schema:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import cuid from 'cuid';
import timestamps from 'mongoose-timestamp';
import validators from 'mongoose-validators';

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Schema({
  auth0id: { type: 'String', required: true },
  cuid: { type: 'String', default: cuid(), required: true },
  dateAdded: { type: 'Date', default: Date.now, required: true },
  email: { type: 'String', required: true, validate: validators.isEmail() },
  avatarURL: { type: 'String', required: true, validate: validators.isURL() },
  username: { type: 'String' },
  accessLevel: { type: 'Number', required: true },
  entities: [{ type: 'String', required: true }],
  preferredEntity: { type: 'String', required: true },
  tab_access: [{
    entityid: { type: 'String', required: true },
    tabs: [{ type: 'String' }],
  }],
  departments: [{
    entitytid: { type: 'String', required: true },
    deptid: { type: 'String', required: true },
  }],
});

userSchema.plugin(timestamps);

export default mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

and I've got some data that I've processed:

```
{
    email: 'client.a@thejump.tech',
    username: 'Fred Bloggs',
    accessLevel: 5,
    entities: ['cit98hg1j000578jcffur7c6h'],
    auth0id: 'auth0|57ff79140dd70f9616b80a9d',
    avatarURL: 'https://s.gravatar.com/avatar/2dfc6cb16eea798886af841e7b1ee8ab?s=480&r=pg&d=https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.auth0.com%2Favatars%2Ffb.png',
    preferredEntity: 'cit98hg1j000578jcffur7c6h',
    departments: [{
        entityid: 'cit98hg1j000578jcffur7c6h',
        deptid: 'cit98hg1j000572jcffur7c6h'
    }],
    tabAccess: [{
        entityid: 'cit98hg1j000578jcffur7c6h',
        tabs: []
    }]
}
```

When I create a new model:

```
const mongoUser = new User(userData);
```

...the data is not the same (N.B. Not saved at this point):

```
{
    email: 'client.a@thejump.tech',
    username: 'Fred Bloggs',
    accessLevel: 5,
    auth0id: 'auth0|57ff79140dd70f9616b80a9d',
    avatarURL: 'https://s.gravatar.com/avatar/2dfc6cb16eea798886af841e7b1ee8ab?s=480&r=pg&d=https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.auth0.com%2Favatars%2Ffb.png',
    preferredEntity: 'cit98hg1j000578jcffur7c6h',
    _id: 57 ff791473da244be87f0489,
    departments: [{
        deptid: 'cit98hg1j000572jcffur7c6h',
        _id: 57 ff791473da244be87f048a
    }],
    tab_access: [],
    entities: ['cit98hg1j000578jcffur7c6h'],
    dateAdded: Thu Oct 13 2016 13: 07: 48 GMT + 0100(BST),
    cuid: 'ciu8aq0430000k7jck2zsi5zm'
}
```

It faults when it:

1. Wipes the `tab_access` data
2. Removes the `entityid` from departments and replaces it with _id

Does anyone know why?? Any help would be really appreciated...

****EDIT****

So, just to be clear, my route handler looks like this:

```
export function addUser(req, res) {
  const sentUser = req.body.user;
  console.log('sentUser', sentUser);
  const newUser = {
    connection: process.env.AUTH0_DB_CONNECTION,
    password: process.env.AUTH0_DEFAULT_PASSWORD,
    username: sentUser.username,
    nickname: sentUser.username,
    email: sentUser.email,
    email_verified: false,
    app_metadata: {
      accessLevel: sentUser.accessLevel,
    },
  };
  console.log('newUser', newUser);
  management.createUser(newUser).then(user => {
    console.log('user returned on auth0 creation: ', user);
    const storedUser = { ...req.body.user };
    console.log('storedUser pre', storedUser);
    storedUser.auth0id = user.user_id;
    storedUser.avatarURL = user.picture;
    storedUser.preferredEntity = storedUser.entities[0].entityid;
    storedUser.departments = storedUser.entities.map((ent) => {
      return {
        entityid: ent.entityid,
        deptid: ent.deptid,
      };
    });
    storedUser.tabAccess = storedUser.entities.map((ent) => {
      return {
        entityid: ent.entityid,
        tabs: [],
      };
    });
    storedUser.entities = storedUser.entities.map((ent) => {
      return ent.entityid;
    });
    console.log('storedUser post', storedUser);
    const mongoUser = new User(storedUser);
    console.log('mongoUser', mongoUser);
    mongoUser.save((err, saved) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log('problem saving', err);
        return res.status(500).send(err);
      }
      return res.status(201).send({ user: saved });
    });
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log('problem saving to Auth0')
    return res.status(500).send(err);
  });
}
```

where `management` is the auto0 management client. I rearrange the data to make `storedUser` and then I make a new model by passing that data in the `new User(storedUser)` and attempt to save the model. Before saving the model I logged out what had been produced and saw the issues noted above.

The two objects I show are the `storedUser`(post) and the `mongoUser` that it produces.

Comment: Can you edit the question and add the query that you execute to insert the document?

Comment: @Svabael At this stage I've not saved it to mongo. I do `mongoUser.save()` next...

Comment: The mongoUser.save will save the document in mongo

Comment: Is it just arrays that are not saving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason is wrong key name:

```
departments: [{
    entitytid: // change it in schema to "entityid"
```

notice the spelling of "entitytid". it should be "entityid".

Second, `tab_access and tabAccess`. you have tab_access in schema but you are passing tabAccess at the time of creating object.

correct this key while you are creating "storedUser".

Comment: Thanks @Sachin, sorry it was such a basic thing. :(

Answer (score 0):

I have a sense, without being 100% sure, that you have to define the schema like that:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import cuid from 'cuid';
import timestamps from 'mongoose-timestamp';
import validators from 'mongoose-validators';

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const tabAccessSchema = new Schema({
  entityid: { type: 'String', required: true },
  tabs: [{ type: 'String' }],
});

const departmentsSchema = new Schema({
  entitytid: { type: 'String', required: true },
  deptid: { type: 'String', required: true },
});

const userSchema = new Schema({
  auth0id: { type: 'String', required: true },
  cuid: { type: 'String', default: cuid(), required: true },
  dateAdded: { type: 'Date', default: Date.now, required: true },
  email: { type: 'String', required: true, validate: validators.isEmail() },
  avatarURL: { type: 'String', required: true, validate: validators.isURL() },
  username: { type: 'String' },
  accessLevel: { type: 'Number', required: true },
  entities: [{ type: 'String', required: true }],
  preferredEntity: { type: 'String', required: true },
  tab_access: [tabAccessSchema],
  departments: [departmentsSchema],
});

userSchema.plugin(timestamps);

export default mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```